# BNO05 IMU + ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently purchased the BNO05 IMU and wish to start publishing sensor_msgs/Imu data on my ROS network. The sensor is connected to an Arduino Uno board which is then connected to my computer. I've found sample code for the IMU which obtains quaternion data from the sensor and displays it on the serial monitor.

I've tried to modify the code so that a node is created which publishes the data in the sensor_msgs/IMU format. The problem is that once this extra code is added, the serial monitor starts outputting rubbish. I believe that this might be due to delays.

Does anyone have experience with this particular IMU?

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BNO055.h>
#include <utility/imumaths.h>
#include <ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Imu.h>

/* 

   Connections

   ===========
   Connect SCL to analog 5
   Connect SDA to analog 4
   Connect VDD to 3-5V DC
   Connect GROUND to common ground

   History
   =======
   2015/MAR/03  - First release (KTOWN)
   2015/AUG/27  - Added calibration and system status helpers
*/

/* Set the delay between fresh samples */
#define BNO055_SAMPLERATE_DELAY_MS (1000)

sensor_msgs::Imu odom_msg;
ros::Publisher pub_odom("imuOdom", &odom_msg);
ros::NodeHandle nh;

Adafruit_BNO055 bno = Adafruit_BNO055(55);

/**************************************************************************/
/*
    Displays some basic information on this sensor from the unified
    sensor API sensor_t type (see Adafruit_Sensor for more information)
*
/
/**************************************************************************/
void displaySensorDetails(void)
{
  sensor_t sensor;
  bno.getSensor(&sensor);
  Serial.println("------------------------------------");
  Serial.print  ("Sensor:       "); Serial.println(sensor.name);
  Serial.print  ("Driver Ver:   "); Serial.println(sensor.version);
  Serial.print  ("Unique ID:    "); Serial.println(sensor.sensor_id);
  Serial.print  ("Max Value:    "); Serial.print(sensor.max_value); Serial.println(" xxx");
  Serial.print  ("Min Value:    "); Serial.print(sensor.min_value); Serial.println(" xxx");
  Serial.print  ("Resolution:   "); Serial.print(sensor.resolution); Serial.println(" xxx");



Serial.println("------------------------------------");

  Serial.println("");
  delay(500);
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*
    Display some basic info about the sensor status
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void displaySensorStatus(void)
{
  /* Get the system status values (mostly for debugging purposes) */

  uint8_t system_status, self_test_results, system_error;
  system_status = self_test_results = system_error = 0;
  bno.getSystemStatus(&system_status, &self_test_results, &system_error);

  /* Display the results in the Serial Monitor */
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("System Status: 0x");
  Serial.println(system_status, HEX);
  Serial.print("Self Test:     0x");
  Serial.println(self_test_results, HEX);
  Serial.print("System Error:  0x");

  Serial.println(system_error, HEX);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(500);
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*
    Display sensor calibration status
*/
/**************************************************************************/

    void displayCalStatus(void)
{
  /* Get the four calibration values (0..3) */
  /* Any sensor data reporting 0 should be ignored, */
  /* 3 means 'fully calibrated" */
  uint8_t system, gyro, accel, mag;
  system = gyro = accel = mag = 0;
  bno.getCalibration(&system, &gyro, &accel, &mag);

  /* The data should be ignored until the system calibration is > 0 */
  Serial.print("\t");
  if (!system)
  {

    Serial.print("! ");
  }

  /* Display the individual values */
  Serial.print("Sys:");
  Serial.print(system, DEC);
  Serial.print(" G:");
  Serial.print(gyro, DEC);
  Serial.print(" A:");
  Serial.print(accel, DEC);
  Serial.print(" M:");

  Serial.print(mag, DEC);
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*
    Arduino setup function (automatically called at startup)
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void setup(void)
{ 
  nh.initNode(); 

  nh.advertise(pub_odom);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Orientation Sensor Test"); Serial.println("");
  
  /* Initialise the sensor */
  if(!bno.begin())
  {
    /* There was a problem detecting the BNO055 ... check your connections */
    Serial.print("Ooops, no BNO055 detected ... Check your wiring or I2C ADDR!");
    while(1);
  }

  delay(1000);

  bno.setExtCrystalUse(true);
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*
    Arduino loop function, called once 'setup' is complete 
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void loop(void)
{
  

/* Display the floating point data */
  imu::Quaternion quat = bno.getQuat();
  
  odom_msg.orientation.x = quat.x();
  odom_msg.orientation.y = quat.y();

  odom_msg.orientation.z = quat.z();
  odom_msg.orientation.w = quat.w();
  odom_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[0] = -1;
  odom_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[0] = -1;
  odom_msg.header.frame_id = "imu";
  pub_odom.publish(&odom_msg);
 
  /* Display the quat data */
  Serial.print("qW: ");
  Serial.print(quat.w(), 4);

  Serial.print(" qX: ");
  Serial.print(quat.y(), 4);
  Serial.print(" qY: ");
  Serial.print(quat.x(), 4);
  Serial.print(" qZ: ");
     

 Serial.print(quat.z(), 4);
 

   Serial.println("");
  /* Optional: Display sensor status (debug only) */
  //displaySensorStatus();

  /* New line for the next sample */
  Serial.println("");
  
  nh.spinOnce();
  /* Wait the specified delay before requesting nex data */
  delay(BNO055_SAMPLERATE_DELAY_MS);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260810/bno05-imu-+-ros/) by [MattMalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/28599/mattmalt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The problem is that once this extra code is added, the serial monitor starts outputting rubbish. I believe that this might be due to delays.

No. You cannot use the same serial port for both rosserial *and* regular output (ie: `Serial.begin(..)`, etc).

If you have more serial ports, use another one for the serial monitor. If you don't, don't do anything with it yourself (not even `Serial.begin(..)`), but let rosserial use it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MattMalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/28599/mattmalt/) on 2017-05-02**:
I've removed the serial outputs to the monitor, but I'm now getting this error message :

**[ERROR] [WallTime: 1493716237.303846] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino**

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-02**:
There are multiple Q&A's about that here on ROS Answers. A first check: make sure you don't do *anything* with the serial port directly, anywhere in your code.

**Comment by [MattMalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/28599/mattmalt/) on 2017-05-02**:
I found that the reason that the board wasn't connecting with ROS was because of the different baud rates. Entering the line **nh.getHardware()->setBaud(57600);** before nh.initNode() solved the problem, and I am seeing the topics published on ROS.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-02**:
Good find. 'anything' was a bit strong.

9k6 is a bit on the slow side, so increasing it is indeed a good idea. On the ROS side, setting the baud rate is done using the `baud` parameter ([wiki/rosserial_python - Parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_python#Parameters)).

**Comment by [femitof](https://answers.ros.org/users/39985/femitof/) on 2020-02-08**:
Hi...How do i see  the topics published in ROS, i am currently running it on my IDE which is interfaced with ROS, but i cant see the topics published in ROS..

How do i go about this?